# Node js exec command

Tags: node.js

I want to execute the command which takes two arguments. I tried the below step but it is not working. Please help

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var inputfile = "./uploads/EM_spectrum.ppt";
var outfile = "./uploads/EM_spectrum.ppt.pdf"
exec('./px-8-5-4-win-x86-64/sdk/demo/pxsample.exe', [inputfile, outfile]);
```

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-launch-child-processes-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var inputfile = "./uploads/EM_spectrum.ppt";
var outfile = "./uploads/EM_spectrum.ppt.pdf";
exec(`./px-8-5-4-win-x86-64/sdk/demo/pxsample.exec ${inputfile} ${outfile}``, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```